# Where can i download 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0'?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mysql

One of my client's Dll depend on 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0'

when i use that dll it give error

Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0..... blah blah

So please where can i download this version of dll...

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: I have The type 'System.Data.IDbConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' error. Any Solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try here: ftp://mysql.sh.cvut.cz/mysqlDownloads/Connector-Net/